# Assignment of Value Statement Not Running Properly inside If-Elif-Else Statement

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a new column (called 'ContractEnding') based on the values in 'Contract' and 'tenure' column valuess.

If the value for Contract is 'Two year' and the tenure%24 is 0,1,or 23 (i.e. 23, 24, 25, 47, 48, 49, 59, 60, or 61), I want to set the value for ContractEnding as 1.

If I add a print statement inside the if statement, it will print, but the value never gets changed. They are the only statements within the if statement, so they should both run.

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
df['tenure'].astype(int)
df['ContractEnding'] = 0
for idx,val in enumerate(df['Contract']):
    if df.iloc[idx]['Contract'] == 'Two year' and df.iloc[idx]['tenure']%24 in [23,0,1]:
        df.iloc[idx]['ContractEnding'] = 1
        ## Print statement here prints fine
    elif df.iloc[idx]['Contract'] == 'One year' and df.iloc[idx]['tenure']%12 in [11,0,1]:
        df.iloc[idx]['ContractEnding'] = 1
    else:
        df.iloc[idx]['ContractEnding'] = 0
```

Comment: It's probably the way you are trying to set the data with `iloc` in pandas, the way you double index this way means you are probably setting the value on a copy.  Try indexing directly w/something like [idx, '...']

Comment: @lemonhead If there's a better way to reference the cell values directly, I'd love to know it. This is the only one that worked at all.